# Named Entity Tagger

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I have made a function that extracts Gpe but it doesn't work. 
The error generated is "invalid syntax" in the line that i will underline with * * in the code.

```
def EstraiLuoghi(frasi): 
TokensTOT = []
TokensPOStot = []
NamedGPE = []
for frase in frasi:
    tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(frase)
    tokensPOS=nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    analisi=nltk.ne_chunk(tokensPOS)
    for nodo in analisi:    
        NE=''
        if hasattr(nodo, 'label'):  
            if nodo.label() in ["GPE"]:
                for partNE in nodo.leaves():   
                    NE=NE+' '+partNE[0]
                NamedGPE.append(NE)    
    TokensTOT=TokensTOT+tokens
TokensPOStot=TokensPOStot+tokensPOS
return TokensTOT, TokensPOStot, NamedGPE


TokensTOT1, TokensPOStot1, NamedGPEC1 = EstraiLuoghi(frasi1)********   
freqGPEC1 = nltk.FreqDist(NamedGPEC1)                       
luoghiOrdinatiC1 = freqGPEC1.most_common(20) 

TokensTOT2, TokensPOStot2, NamedGPEC2 = EstraiLuoghi(frasi2)    
freqGPEC2 = nltk.FreqDist(NamedGPEC2)   
luoghiOrdinatiC2 = freqGPEC2.most_common(20)
```

Comment: Your syntax error is probably due to an indentation error, but it's impossible to tell from the code that is posted because there is more than one indentation error.

Comment: You may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve].